# Как спрятать свой api ключ в jquery?

Tags: jquery

Делаю отправку и получение запросов на сайте через jquery, при этом я использую свой api ключ для взаимодействия со сторонним сервисом, как я могу спрятать свой уникальный api ключ что бы его нельзя было увидеть через код страницы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, ты только можешь усложнить логику своего клиентского приложения, путем запутывания кода, либо можешь отправлять запросы к стороннему API через свой сервер, где будет использоваться ключ, тогда не придется передавать ключ клиенту.